# Mongodb replica failures to resolve DNS when primary DNS is stopped while secondary DNS is operational

Tags: domain-name-system, failover, mongodb, internal-dns

1. I have setup mongod replica consisted of 3 nodes + 1 delayed hidden node + arbiter.
2. I have setup DNS: primary and secondary internal DNS (bind) servers, so that I can reference nodes by normal FQDN name instead of IP address.
3. I have secondary DNS to handle requests while (if) primary is down.

### **Problem**:

When I simulate primary DNS down - I totally break Replica Set, as master node - doesn't see other nodes and becomes SECONDARY 5-10 seconds later

---

this what my primary node (mongodb-cluster-shard-01-rA.site-aws.com) displays when primary DNS is shut down:

```
siteRS0:SECONDARY> rs.status()
{
        "set" : "siteRS0",
        "date" : ISODate("2014-08-10T03:16:22Z"),
        "myState" : 2,
        "members" : [
                {
                        "_id" : 0,
                        "name" : "mongodb-cluster-shard-01-rA.site-aws.com:27017",
                        "health" : 1,
                        "state" : 2,
                        "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
                        "uptime" : 1913839,
                        "optime" : Timestamp(1407628608, 1),
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2014-08-09T23:56:48Z"),
                        "self" : true
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 1,
                        "name" : "mongodb-cluster-shard-01-rB.site-aws.com:27017",
                        "health" : 0,
                        "state" : 8,
                        "stateStr" : "(not reachable/healthy)",
                        "uptime" : 0,
                        "optime" : Timestamp(1407628608, 1),
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2014-08-09T23:56:48Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2014-08-10T03:16:08Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2014-08-10T03:15:52Z"),
                        "pingMs" : 0,
                        "syncingTo" : "mongodb-cluster-shard-01-rA.site-aws.com:27017"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 2,
                        "name" : "mongodb-cluster-shard-01-arbiter.site-aws.com:30000",
                        "health" : 0,
                        "state" : 8,
                        "stateStr" : "(not reachable/healthy)",
                        "uptime" : 0,
                        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2014-08-10T03:16:19Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2014-08-10T03:15:45Z"),
                        "pingMs" : 0
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 3,
                        "name" : "mongodb-cluster-shard-01-rC.site-aws.com:27017",
                        "health" : 0,
                        "state" : 8,
                        "stateStr" : "(not reachable/healthy)",
                        "uptime" : 0,
                        "optime" : Timestamp(1407628608, 1),
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2014-08-09T23:56:48Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2014-08-10T03:16:16Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2014-08-10T03:15:52Z"),
                        "pingMs" : 0,
                        "syncingTo" : "mongodb-cluster-shard-01-rA.site-aws.com:27017"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : 4,
                        "name" : "mongodb-cluster-shard-01-rA-backup-hidden.site-aws.com:27017",
                        "health" : 0,
                        "state" : 8,
                        "stateStr" : "(not reachable/healthy)",
                        "uptime" : 0,
                        "optime" : Timestamp(1407628608, 1),
                        "optimeDate" : ISODate("2014-08-09T23:56:48Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2014-08-10T03:16:00Z"),
                        "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2014-08-10T03:15:49Z"),
                        "pingMs" : 0,
                        "syncingTo" : "mongodb-cluster-shard-01-rA.site-aws.com:27017"
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1
}
```

if I go to the log I see a lot of getaddrinfo messages:

```
[root@mongodb-cluster-shard-01-rA ec2-user]# tail /mongo/log/mongod.log 
2014-08-10T02:35:13.044+0000 [rsHealthPoll] getaddrinfo("mongodb-cluster-shard-01-arbiter.site-aws.com") failed: Name or service not known
2014-08-10T02:35:13.469+0000 [rsHealthPoll] getaddrinfo("mongodb-cluster-shard-01-rC.site-aws.com") failed: Name or service not known
2014-08-10T02:35:13.469+0000 [rsHealthPoll] couldn't connect to mongodb-cluster-shard-01-rC.site-aws.com:27017: couldn't connect to server mongodb-cluster-shard-01-rC.site-aws.com:27017 (0.0.0.0) failed, address resolved to 0.0.0.0
2014-08-10T02:35:13.968+0000 [rsHealthPoll] getaddrinfo("mongodb-cluster-shard-01-rA-backup-hidden.site-aws.com") failed: Name or service not known
2014-08-10T02:35:13.968+0000 [rsHealthPoll] couldn't connect to mongodb-cluster-shard-01-rA-backup-hidden.site-aws.com:27017: couldn't connect to server mongodb-cluster-shard-01-rA-backup-hidden.site-aws.com:27017 (0.0.0.0) failed, address resolved to 0.0.0.0
2014-08-10T02:35:17.059+0000 [rsHealthPoll] getaddrinfo("mongodb-cluster-shard-01-rB.site-aws.com") failed: Name or service not known
2014-08-10T02:35:17.059+0000 [rsHealthPoll] couldn't connect to mongodb-cluster-shard-01-rB.site-aws.com:27017: couldn't connect to server mongodb-cluster-shard-01-rB.site-aws.com:27017 (0.0.0.0) failed, address resolved to 0.0.0.0
2014-08-10T02:35:18.476+0000 [rsHealthPoll] getaddrinfo("mongodb-cluster-shard-01-rC.site-aws.com") failed: Name or service not known
2014-08-10T02:35:18.669+0000 [rsHealthPoll] couldn't connect to mongodb-cluster-shard-01-rC.site-aws.com:27017: couldn't connect to server mongodb-cluster-shard-01-rC.site-aws.com:27017 (0.0.0.0) failed, address resolved to 0.0.0.0
2014-08-10T02:35:18.976+0000 [rsHealthPoll] getaddrinfo("mongodb-cluster-shard-01-rA-backup-hidden.site-aws.com") failed: Name or service not known
[root@mongodb-cluster-shard-01-rA ec2-user]# tail /mongo/log/mongod.log 
2014-08-10T02:35:17.059+0000 [rsHealthPoll] getaddrinfo("mongodb-cluster-shard-01-rB.site-aws.com") failed: Name or service not known
2014-08-10T02:35:17.059+0000 [rsHealthPoll] couldn't connect to mongodb-cluster-shard-01-rB.site-aws.com:27017: couldn't connect to server mongodb-cluster-shard-01-rB.site-aws.com:27017 (0.0.0.0) failed, address resolved to 0.0.0.0
2014-08-10T02:35:18.476+0000 [rsHealthPoll] getaddrinfo("mongodb-cluster-shard-01-rC.site-aws.com") failed: Name or service not known
2014-08-10T02:35:18.669+0000 [rsHealthPoll] couldn't connect to mongodb-cluster-shard-01-rC.site-aws.com:27017: couldn't connect to server mongodb-cluster-shard-01-rC.site-aws.com:27017 (0.0.0.0) failed, address resolved to 0.0.0.0
2014-08-10T02:35:18.976+0000 [rsHealthPoll] getaddrinfo("mongodb-cluster-shard-01-rA-backup-hidden.site-aws.com") failed: Name or service not known
2014-08-10T02:35:20.051+0000 [rsHealthPoll] getaddrinfo("mongodb-cluster-shard-01-arbiter.site-aws.com") failed: Name or service not known
2014-08-10T02:35:20.051+0000 [rsHealthPoll] couldn't connect to mongodb-cluster-shard-01-arbiter.site-aws.com:30000: couldn't connect to server mongodb-cluster-shard-01-arbiter.site-aws.com:30000 (0.0.0.0) failed, address resolved to 0.0.0.0
2014-08-10T02:35:23.677+0000 [rsHealthPoll] getaddrinfo("mongodb-cluster-shard-01-rC.site-aws.com") failed: Name or service not known
2014-08-10T02:35:24.066+0000 [rsHealthPoll] getaddrinfo("mongodb-cluster-shard-01-rB.site-aws.com") failed: Name or service not known
2014-08-10T02:35:24.066+0000 [rsHealthPoll] couldn't connect to mongodb-cluster-shard-01-rB.site-aws.com:27017: couldn't connect to server mongodb-cluster-shard-01-rB.site-aws.com:27017 (0.0.0.0) failed, address resolved to 0.0.0.0
[root@mongodb-cluster-shard-01-rA ec2-user]#
```

### however nslookup resolve FQDN to IP properly:

```
[root@mongodb-cluster-shard-01-rA ec2-user]# nslookup mongodb-cluster-shard-01-rC.site-aws.com
Server:         10.233.147.18 (this is secondary dns)
Address:        10.233.147.18#53

Name:   mongodb-cluster-shard-01-rC.site-aws.com
Address: 10.220.153.211
```

**after I start the primary dns (.119):**
then soon I will get it resolved by primary DNS

```
[root@mongodb-cluster-shard-01-rA ec2-user]# nslookup mongodb-cluster-shard-01-rC.site-aws.com
Server:         10.35.147.119
Address:        10.35.147.119#53
```

---

I get everything back to normal once primary DNS is up & running. My replica gets primary and all is OK. 
So what did I miss or doing wrong?

---

### my mongo instances have the following /etc/resolve.conf file:

```
[root@mongodb-cluster-shard-01-rA log]# cat /etc/resolv.conf
; generated by /sbin/dhclient-script
search us-west-2.compute.internal site.com
nameserver 10.35.147.119
nameserver 10.233.147.18
nameserver 172.16.0.23
nameserver 172.16.0.23
```

### primary DNS /etc/named.conf:

```
options {
        #listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; 10.224.3.36};
        listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
        directory       "/var/named";
        dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
        memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
        allow-query     { any; };
        recursion no;

        dnssec-enable yes;
        dnssec-validation yes;
        dnssec-lookaside auto;

        /* Path to ISC DLV key */
        bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";

        managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";
        notify yes;
        also-notify { 10.233.147.18; };

};

logging {
        channel default_debug {
                file "data/named.run";
                severity dynamic;
        };
};

zone "site-aws.com" IN {
                type master;
                file "site-aws.com.zone";
                allow-update { none; };
                allow-query { any; };
                allow-transfer {10.233.147.18; };
};


include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";
```

**"site-aws.com.zone" defined:**

```
$TTL 86400
@   IN  SOA     ns1.site-aws.com. root.site-aws.com. (
        2013042203  ;Serial
        300         ;Refresh
        1800        ;Retry
        604800      ;Expire
        86400       ;Minimum TTL
)
; Specify our two nameservers
                IN      NS              ns1.site-aws.com.
;               IN      NS              ns2.site-aws.com.
; Resolve nameserver hostnames to IP, replace with your two droplet IP addresses.
ns1             IN      A               10.224.3.36
;ns2            IN      A               2.2.2.2

; Define hostname -> IP pairs which you wish to resolve
devops                                     IN   A   10.35.147.119
mongodb-cluster-shard-01-rA                IN   A   10.230.9.223
mongodb-cluster-shard-01-rB                IN   A   10.17.6.57
mongodb-cluster-shard-01-rC                IN   A   10.220.153.211
mongodb-cluster-shard-01-arbiter           IN   A   10.251.112.114
mongodb-cluster-shard-01-rA-backup-hidden  IN   A   10.230.20.83
mongodb-cluster-backup                     IN   A   10.230.20.83
prod-redis-cluster-01-rA                   IN   A   10.226.207.86
ns1                                        IN   A   10.35.147.119
ns2   

                                 IN   A   10.233.147.18
```

**secondary DNS /etc/named.conf:**

```
options {
        #listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; 10.224.3.36};
        listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
        directory       "/var/named";
        dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
        memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
        allow-query     { any; };
        recursion no;

        dnssec-enable yes;
        dnssec-validation yes;
        dnssec-lookaside auto;

        /* Path to ISC DLV key */
        bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";

        managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";
};

logging {
        channel default_debug {
                file "data/named.run";
                severity dynamic;
        };
};

zone "site-aws.com" IN {
                type slave;
                file "site-aws.com.zone";
                allow-query { any; };
                allow-transfer {10.35.147.119; }; ## NS1 is allowed for zone transfer when necessary ##
                masters {10.35.147.119; }; ## the master NS1 is defined ##
        };

include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";
```

secondary dns got synced site-aws.com.zone - file exists.

So question, why replica mongodb is behaved that way. How can I make sure that if primary DNS gets down, replica (and all other nodes that references internal nodes by FQDN remain operational)

Comment: Just to note, the question is misleading because that's not a crash - it's just a failure to resolve the address because it's not failing over to the secondary DNS - a crash would mean that the mongod completely shuts down which is not happening here (and would mean something very different)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was in glibc, that's caching /etc/resolve.conf data. I have fixed this by installing nscd:

```
yum install nscd; chkconfig nscd on; /etc/init.d/nscd start
```

After that the problem is gone. Several related topics:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125466/using-glibc-why-does-my-gethostbyname-fail-after-i-dhcp-has-changed-the-dns-ser
2. https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-7587
3. https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-12099

Hope this helps someone in future.